# How to use styled-component CSS props with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I map over an array of colors, which is defined in the database. I want to pass this colors as background for the created divs. Like I am used to, the console shows me, that the colors out of the array are passed in as prop. But using the props in styled components not works in typescript. I tried the following, what I have found in the net:

> import * as types from 'styled-components/cssprop'
>
> import type {} from 'styled-components/cssprop';

```
/// <reference types="styled-components/cssprop" />
```

I only passed this variations into my file.
The both snippets:

```
<ColorHolder>
    {item.colors.map((color)=>(
     <div color={color}></div>
      ))}
    </ColorHolder>
```

css:

```
 & div{
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        border-radius:50%;
        background:${props=>props.color};
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your code, you don't need to use any libraries.
Here is the working example, where `colors` in the array you fetched from backend

```
<div>
{
colors.map(color=>(
    <div style={{backgroundColor: color, height: "50px",width: "50px"}}>
    .
    </div>))
}
</div>
```

Here's full example - [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/embed/sweet-burnell-9frcep?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thank you, I was used to take the library, but so it works either.

Answer (score 2):

Only styled components can receive props for this style adaptation technique.

Therefore in your case simply create a quick styled `div`:

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div<{ color: string }>`
  background: ${props => props.color};
`;

<ColorHolder>
  {item.colors.map((color) => (
    <StyledDiv color={color}></StyledDiv>
  ))}
</ColorHolder>
```

Comment: Thanks ghybs, that's a great tip.